# Save extracted value as HTML file in iMacros

Tags: macros, imacros, browser-automation

I wrote this code for iMacros:

```
SET !EXTRACT '<html><head></head><body><p>TEST</p></body></html>'
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=E:\MyFolder FILE=test.html
```

But instead of HTML file, I get CSV file with name "test.html" and extension ".csv"

Same goes if I try with FILE=test.txt or any other format, it simply always saves files with CSV extension.

Is there any way to change file extension?

Comment: This way: `SAVEAS TYPE=HTM FOLDER=E:\MyFolder FILE=test` . [More info](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS).

Comment: @Shugar that saves current opened webpage's code to HTML. I need to save only value of EXTRACT variable into test.html page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this workaround will be helpful to you:

```
SET !EXTRACT "<html><head></head><body><p>TEST</p></body></html>"
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/</g, '&lt').replace(/>/g, '&gt');")
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=javascript:'{{!EXTRACT}}';
WAIT SECONDS=0.5
SAVEAS TYPE=TXT FOLDER=E:\MyFolder FILE=test.html
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
```